# Boolean array and a simple way to try every combination

Tags: java, arrays, boolean-logic

So at the moment i am writing some code for my last comp sci paper, it requires you to red in some input on system.in, process it, first line is always a set of numbers upto 25 numbers. This is followed by a single N or L, and another int which is the aim. Using this input you have to find the the right set of operations (+ and *) that uses the int values to create the aim.

I am using a Boolean array to keep track of what operands i am using in very check however I'm unsure how to "brute force" the solution by trying every different set of operands, i have the code to check each set however Im not sure if there is an simple and easy way to change the array by such as [0,0,0,0] (0 is false) to [0,0,0,1], [0,0,1,0], [0,0,1,1] etc?

Im sure there is a really simple way i have overlooked but for the life of me i am unsure of what it is atm.

```
static boolean evlN(int[] input, boolean[]ops, int aim){
    boolean run = true, found = false;
    int[] used = new int[input.length];
    int runs = 0 ,ans = 0;
    while(!found && runs < (1 << ops.length)){
        //finding all multiplys and doing them first
        search:
        for(int x = 0; x < ops.length; x++){
            if(!ops[x]){
                used[x] = input[x] * input[x+1];
                //need to stop working out and change the ops
                if(used[x] > aim){
                    run = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        //once multiplys have been done need to do all the adds
        if(run){
            for(int x = 0; x < ops.length; x++){
                if(ops[x]){
                    if(used[x] != 0) ans += used[x] + input[x+1];
                    else if(used[x+1] != 0) ans += input[x] + used[x];
                }
                if(ans > aim) break;
            }
        }
        if(ans == aim) found = true;
        used = new int[input.length];
        ans= 0;
        runs++;
        run = !run;
    }
    if(found) return true;
    else return false;

}
```

this is what im using to work out each set of operands and numbers i just trying to change the boolean array to brute force the answer

Comment: `i have the code to check each set` ... can you show us this code?

Comment: You can use a bit set instead of a boolean array and just increment.

Comment: @shmosel how do you use a bit set? i know you can do 1 << bitset or am i wrong, im unsure because i have never worked with them before

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen just added to the post

Comment: @NexMetu _"i have never worked with them"_ -- This is where you go to the Javadoc and look them up.

Comment: @JimGarrison yep i fail, sorry looked up binaryset instead of bitset thanks guys

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is a fairly generic mechanism that can be used to increment through a set of combination, just as you would do for digits in an integer. I'll demonstrate it using an interface so you can see how it can be applied in general.

```
public interface UnitValue {
    boolean isLast();
    UnitValue next();
}

public class <T extends UnitValue> MultiUnitValue {
    private final int size;
    private final T first;
    private final T[] units;
    private boolean complete = false;

    public MultiUnitValue(int size, T first) {
        this.size = size;
        this.first = first;
        this.units = new T[size];
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            units[i] = first;
    }

    public void next() {
        if (!complete) {
            int i = 0;
            while (units[i].isLast())
                units[i++] = first;
            units[i].next();
            complete = i == size - 1 && units[i].isLast();
        }
    }
}
```

I've left out getters for clarity but they should be obvious.

For a non-generic solution for booleans it'd look like:

```
boolean[] values = new boolean[size];

int i = 0;
while (values[i])
    values[i++] = false;
values[i] = true;
```

A very similar solution works for characters, digits, enums and anything else that fits the same pattern.

Comment: YES,this is what i was looking for, thank you. My brain is mush atm and iI knew it was something like this but thank you for the answer saved me spending another day on this task.

Answer (score 0):

Your set of input combinations looks like a binary integer (call it `N`). You can progress through the different combinations by incrementing `N`.